# Check if class being used?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Simple problem,
is it possible to check if a class is being used or not?

```
class A { }
class B { }

class TestClass
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new A();
    }
}
```

I want to loop through all classes with reflection and get back that **A is being used** somewhere.
By "used" I mean there is a reference to it somewhere, it does not need to be loaded necessarily already. In the same way Visual Studio show how many references an object has.

Comment: Sounds like a classic XY problem. What exactly are you trying to achieve by knowing that information? Also, what do you mean by _"it does not need to be loaded necessarily already"_?

Comment: _Shift+F12_ Find all references

Comment: In my case I have many services with some shared projects, and I have maybe 100 exceptionClasses but only 10 being used in this service, and I need to know which 10 is relevant for this service. Of course I can do some kind of list but it would be awesome to just have it automagical :-) "not need to be loaded"=the result of classes is the same regardless if I get the list before or after the line "var a = new A();"

Comment: Sounds like you need a static code analyzer?

Comment: @stebberg Sounds like you need to make whatever initialization happens for these exceptions happen lazily, on first use, rather than on application start.  Then it won't happen until they are actually used.  it has the benefit that the work isn't done unless they actually happen, rather than if the type is used in the application but never happens to actually get used.

Comment: very interesting Servy!

Comment: What about `Activator.CreateInstance("A")`, how would you detect this? What if the string comes from somewhere and is dynamically constructed so it isn't just specified as a literal in the call to CreateInstance?

Comment: What if the A class is actually referenced in code but there is no way to reach that code, would that count?

Comment: Thank you for that excellent point Lasse, that might be a solution in one case! But in my case unfortunately no, because the base of my problem is to have a swagger generated for me with only the relevant classes (in other words they need to be "hard bounded" :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: My understanding is that unfortunately **it is not possible to see if a class is used or not** using reflection. I've got this hardcore solution tip using the Expression feature but I'm not sure that it is what I'm after.